# Consuming REST APIs in Ruby - When to authenticate?

Tags: ruby, rest

I'll try to keep this as brief and to the point as possible.

I'm writing a Ruby gem, modeled after the Diplomat gem, that's a wrapper around a product's REST API. The API I'm consuming makes use of token based authentication; an API token is sent via a POST, and a session is returned as a cookie. I'm making use of the Faraday cookiejar middleware for handling the cookie that's returned by the API. The problem I'm struggling with, conceptually, is when to authenticate.

I have two classes, one called RestClient and one called Volume; the latter inherits from the former. As it stands now RestClient's init method builds a connection object and authenticates, while Volume's init method calls super and passes a path. My thinking here is that when any class that inherits from RestClient is initialized it'll authenticate the user.

```
class RestClient
  def initialize(api_path)
    <build connection>
    auth
  end
  def auth
    <post token, get session cookie>
  end
end

class Volume < RestClient
  def initialize
    super('/volume')
  end
  def volumes
    <send GET, receive volumes>
  end
end

obj = Volume.new #Creates object, authenticates user
obj.volumes #Returns list of volumes
```

I guess my question is..am I headed down the right track? Should I hold off authenticating until a method is first called on the object, rather than authenticating when it's initialized? Am I going about this entirely incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are asking here is more of a code-style question. there is no right or wrong here. i was about to vote to close because i think it is `primarily opinion-based`.

since i have an opinion, i'm writing an answer instead.

a) do not over-think

just implement the stuff, if it works, it is good enough

b) rule of 3

if you have implemented 3 things of the same kind and a pattern emerges, refactor!

c) refuse to use inheritance

when in doubt, do not use inheritance. a module will be good enough most of the time.

to your question specifically:

i would not use an initializer to make http calls. they are error-prone and error-handling from within initializers or around those is really ugly. it makes testing a pain in the ass.

what i would do is to just implement whatever you need in simple methods.

what is wrong with calling `authenticate` before making another api call? putting it into a block may make it really nice and readable:

```
client.authenticate do |session|
  session.volumes
end
```

if this is too ugly for your use-case, you could do it lazily before any other method call that might require authentication.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I'm quite prone to overthinking. I went with lazily authenticating before each method that makes an API call, which has subsequently made testing a lot easier. I'm going to mark this as the answer for the simple fact that pointing out authenticating during initialization is a poor pattern to follow, and that advice alone was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Is cookie the only auth your API supports? Very often server-oriented (server-to-server) REST APIs also implement better auth strategies that allow you to pass in auth with every request.

All that being said, what you also can do is something like this:

```
 client = MyApi::Client.for_user(username: ..., password: ....)
 #...or
 client = MyApi::Client.for_token(token)
 volumes = MyApi::Volumes.get(client: client)
```

This way for where auth is required you would be doing a good thing by "encouraging your class to be used right" - that you simply won't be instantiating the client without authentication data, and won't be initializing your remote objects/calls without a client.

Then, within the client, what you can do is a memoized auth on first request

```
def perform(http_method, url, ...)
  @auth_cookie ||= @client.get_cookie_by_authentication
  ...
end
```